# Parse known and unknown args with typer cli

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse, typer

with argparse I could parse both the known and the unknown args

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
known, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['--foo', 'BAR', 'spam'])
print(known)
# Namespace(foo='BAR')
print(unknown)
# ['spam']
```

How can you do this with [typer](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running this:

```
from sys import argv

import typer

app = typer.Typer()


@app.command(
    context_settings={"allow_extra_args": True, "ignore_unknown_options": True}
)
def main(foo: str = typer.Option(...), unknown_args: typer.Context = typer.Option(None)):
    typer.echo(f"known arg: {foo}")
    for unknown_arg in unknown_args.args:
        typer.echo(f"Got extra arg: {unknown_arg}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv.extend(["--foo", "BAR", "spam"])
    app()
```

will output:

```
known arg: BAR
Got extra arg: spam
```

source:

- https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/commands/context/#configuring-the-context
- https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/163